# How can i count the number of identical objects by keys in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 },
  { appleID: 24, bananaID: 13}, 
  { appleID: 97, bananaID: 13},
  { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 }
]
```

The result should look like this:

```
[
  { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55, count: 2 },
  { appleID: 24, bananaID: 13, count: 1}, 
  { appleID: 97, bananaID: 13, count: 1}
]
```

Count the number of identical elements by `element === appleID && element === bananaID`

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show us your code what you are trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 },
  { appleID: 24, bananaID: 13}, 
  { appleID: 97, bananaID: 13},
  { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 }
]

function countNum(arr){
    return arr.reduce((pre, item) => {
        const hasItem = pre.find(subItem => subItem.appleID === item.appleID && subItem.bananaID === item.bananaID)
        if(hasItem){
            hasItem.count++
        }else{
            pre.push({...item, count: 1})
        }
        return pre
    }, [])
}

console.log(countNum(data))
```

like this

```js
function countNum(arr){
    return arr.reduce((pre, item) => {
        const hasItem = pre.find(subItem => subItem.appleID === item.appleID && subItem.bananaID === item.bananaID)
        if(hasItem){
            hasItem.count++
        }else{
            pre.push({...item, count: 1})
        }
        return pre
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: In terms of performance, your code is too slow, bro. Actually, you can use `object` to get the highest performance (Find just takes `O(1)`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggregate your data by 2 things below:

1. The key idea is building the `key` with a format like `const key = ${appleID}-${bananaID}`
2. Use In terms of performance, you can use `object` to get the highest performance (Find just takes `O(1)`)

   ```js
   const data = [
     { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 },
     { appleID: 24, bananaID: 13}, 
     { appleID: 97, bananaID: 13},
     { appleID: 13, bananaID: 55 }
   ];

   const result = data.reduce((acc, {appleID, bananaID}) => {
     const key = `${appleID}-${bananaID}`
     acc[key] ??= {appleID, bananaID, count: 0};
     acc[key]["count"] += 1;
     
     return acc;
   }, {});

   console.log(Object.values(result));
   ```

Comment: @Vladislav Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help :)